# Underscores in Lucene outputs with stop words when getting ngram frequencies

Tags: lucene, n-gram

I’m currently giving the user an option to include stop words or not when filtering a body of text for ngram frequencies. Typically, this is done as follows:

```
snowballAnalyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, "English", stopWords);               
shingleAnalyzer = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(snowballAnalyzer, this.getnGramLength());
```

stopWords is set to either a full list of words to include in ngrams or to remove from them. this.getnGramLength()); simply contains the current ngram length up to a maximum of three.

If I use stopwords in filtering text "satellite is definitely falling to Earth" for trigrams, the output is:

```
No=1, Key=to, Freq=1
No=2, Key=definitely, Freq=1
No=3, Key=falling to earth, Freq=1
No=4, Key=satellite, Freq=1
No=5, Key=is, Freq=1
No=6, Key=definitely falling to, Freq=1
No=7, Key=definitely falling, Freq=1
No=8, Key=falling, Freq=1
No=9, Key=to earth, Freq=1
No=10, Key=satellite is, Freq=1
No=11, Key=is definitely, Freq=1
No=12, Key=falling to, Freq=1
No=13, Key=is definitely falling, Freq=1
No=14, Key=earth, Freq=1
No=15, Key=satellite is definitely, Freq=1
```

But if I don’t use stopwords for trigrams, the output is this:

```
No=1, Key=satellite, Freq=1
No=2, Key=falling _, Freq=1
No=3, Key=satellite _ _, Freq=1
No=4, Key=_ earth, Freq=1
No=5, Key=falling, Freq=1
No=6, Key=satellite _, Freq=1
No=7, Key=_ _, Freq=1
No=8, Key=_ falling _, Freq=1
No=9, Key=falling _ earth, Freq=1
No=10, Key=_, Freq=3
No=11, Key=earth, Freq=1
No=12, Key=_ _ falling, Freq=1
No=13, Key=_ falling, Freq=1
```

Why am I seeing underscores? I would have thought to see simple unigrams, “satellite falling”, “falling earth” and “satellite falling earth”? Definitely is in the stopwords set I'm using.

I can just filter out the results with underscores but...

Comment: As of lucene 7, the ShingleFilter has a method called 'setFillerToken()'.  The default filler is underscore.  You can set it to empty string.  Not perfect, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underscores represent a 'missing stop word/s'. To avoid that behavior you should set the `enablePositionIncrements` to `false` but `SnowballAnalyzer` (now deprecated in 4.0.0-Beta) doesn't let you do it.

One solution is using a StandardAnalyzer with no stop words first, and then decorate the output with a `StopFilter`, `SnowballFilter`, and `ShingleFilter`. Example for bi-grams in Lucene 4.0.0-Beta:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("content", new StringReader(input));
StopFilter stopFilter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, tokenStream, stopWords);
stopFilter.setEnablePositionIncrements(false);
SnowballFilter snowballFilter = new SnowballFilter(stopFilter, "English");
ShingleFilter bigramShingleFilter = new ShingleFilter(snowballFilter, 2, 2);
```

Hope that this puts you on the right track!

**EDIT**

Not possible anymore with Lucene v4.4+, still looking for a nice alternative...